# Html path location strange format

Tags: html, syntax, path, formatting, tags

So I've been having a gander at some snazzy websites seeing how they do things and how it's laid out for learning purposes and I encountered some code for the pathing that looks like the below example.

```
<path d="M5.47 7.2l-.55.33a5.14 5.14 0 0 1-3.2-1.28C1.48 6 1.2 5.88.94 5.7A2.39 2.39 0 0 1 0 4.4a7.29 7.29 0 0 1 1.61-1.21c.56-.4 1.13-.78 1.73-1.19l.54.18c.29-.74.29-.75 1-1.1A9.45 9.45 0 0 1 6.23.52 17.77 17.77 0 0 1 8 .14c.09 0 .19.06.29.08s.24.07.28 0A.78.78 0 0 1 9.24 0a5.47 5.47 0 0 1 1.66.09c.38.11.75.26 1.13.37s.35.29.44.56a.7.7 0 0 1 .8 0A8.54 8.54 0 0 1 16 3.54 14.5 14.5 0 0 0 17.11 5a2.55 2.55 0 0 1-1 .92c-.72.39-1.45.77-2.18 1.14s-.65.32-1.09-.24c-.45.09-.41.58-.72.85A13.77 13.77 0 0 1 6.7 8a1.15 1.15 0 0 1-1-.57c-.01-.1-.1-.14-.23-.23zm5.15-3.67c-.16-.35-.26-.62-.41-.87a1.12 1.12 0 0 0-1-.62 4.75 4.75 0 0 0-1.48.26 1.22 1.22 0 0 0-.73.59 9 9 0 0 0-.49 1 .64.64 0 0 0 0 .46c.22.45.47.89.73 1.32a.43.43 0 0 0 .25.19 3.82 3.82 0 0 0 2 0 .76.76 0 0 0 .31-.24 6.42 6.42 0 0 0 .42-.62c.17-.26.33-.54.51-.84l1.27.1c0 .62-.59.85-.7 1.33.18.26.36.43.68.35L15.64 5v-.21a22.24 22.24 0 0 0-3.1-2.73 2.62 2.62 0 0 0-.73-.3 1 1 0 0 0-.75 0c.24.17.46.31.67.48.53.42.57.64.29 1.43zM6.09 6.2c-.3-.4-.53-.68-.74-1a1.1 1.1 0 0 1-.2-.51 3.43 3.43 0 0 1 .36-2.08.9.9 0 0 0 .24-.61 11.53 11.53 0 0 0-1.84 1.2A10.47 10.47 0 0 0 2 4.43l.88.5a5.13 5.13 0 0 1 .76.43 4.57 4.57 0 0 0 2.45.84z"></path>
```

I was wondering why is it laid out like this? For security reasons? And how does something with such a strange path string actually locate the relevant path.

Any information regarding this would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an [SVG path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path).

It describes the path a line takes (not a file path!) using coordinates, lengths, and so on.

It has nothing to do with security.

```html
<svg>
<path d="M5.47 7.2l-.55.33a5.14 5.14 0 0 1-3.2-1.28C1.48 6 1.2 5.88.94 5.7A2.39 2.39 0 0 1 0 4.4a7.29 7.29 0 0 1 1.61-1.21c.56-.4 1.13-.78 1.73-1.19l.54.18c.29-.74.29-.75 1-1.1A9.45 9.45 0 0 1 6.23.52 17.77 17.77 0 0 1 8 .14c.09 0 .19.06.29.08s.24.07.28 0A.78.78 0 0 1 9.24 0a5.47 5.47 0 0 1 1.66.09c.38.11.75.26 1.13.37s.35.29.44.56a.7.7 0 0 1 .8 0A8.54 8.54 0 0 1 16 3.54 14.5 14.5 0 0 0 17.11 5a2.55 2.55 0 0 1-1 .92c-.72.39-1.45.77-2.18 1.14s-.65.32-1.09-.24c-.45.09-.41.58-.72.85A13.77 13.77 0 0 1 6.7 8a1.15 1.15 0 0 1-1-.57c-.01-.1-.1-.14-.23-.23zm5.15-3.67c-.16-.35-.26-.62-.41-.87a1.12 1.12 0 0 0-1-.62 4.75 4.75 0 0 0-1.48.26 1.22 1.22 0 0 0-.73.59 9 9 0 0 0-.49 1 .64.64 0 0 0 0 .46c.22.45.47.89.73 1.32a.43.43 0 0 0 .25.19 3.82 3.82 0 0 0 2 0 .76.76 0 0 0 .31-.24 6.42 6.42 0 0 0 .42-.62c.17-.26.33-.54.51-.84l1.27.1c0 .62-.59.85-.7 1.33.18.26.36.43.68.35L15.64 5v-.21a22.24 22.24 0 0 0-3.1-2.73 2.62 2.62 0 0 0-.73-.3 1 1 0 0 0-.75 0c.24.17.46.31.67.48.53.42.57.64.29 1.43zM6.09 6.2c-.3-.4-.53-.68-.74-1a1.1 1.1 0 0 1-.2-.51 3.43 3.43 0 0 1 .36-2.08.9.9 0 0 0 .24-.61 11.53 11.53 0 0 0-1.84 1.2A10.47 10.47 0 0 0 2 4.43l.88.5a5.13 5.13 0 0 1 .76.43 4.57 4.57 0 0 0 2.45.84z"></path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, much appreciated, I'll mark this as accepted once the time limit has passed.